# Mac OSX Can't see to get Automator to run python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, automator

I have a Python script that does a json.dump of non-ascii text. It works fine with python3 but not with python2. That's fine, I use Anaconda's virtualenv facility to switch to python3 before running it.

But I having trouble trying to do this using Automator in Mac. Every time I have Automator run the script, it throws the same error I always see when I run it with Python2. I have tried everything, including making the script executable wih a shebang line that goes to python3. What am I doing wrong here?

The point here is that python3 handles unicode more gracefully than python2 and that's why I'm trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Oops. It worked to invoke the script with:

> /usr/local/bin/python3 myScript.py

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to the *egilchri* answer.

Following steps worked for me:

1. Open automator, go to: file>new application
2. In the search bar (available in the top left corner) search for `run shell script`
3. Double tap on `Run Shell Script` action
4. Now in the workflow window select shell type as `/bin/zsh`
5. In the editor window type `/usr/local/bin/python3 Desktop/pythonFile.py`
6. Run this script and you have successfully ran python script from automator.